# For in bash with parameters

Tags: bash, for-loop, brace-expansion

I like make a for loop in bash script with parameters, some like this:

```
for VALUE in {"$from".."$to"}
do  
    echo -e "Processing $VALUE \n"

done
```

This no loop, only return: "Processing {1..4}"
It is possible?

Comment: Use `seq` with variables, example: `a=1;b=10;for i in $(seq $a  $b)  ;do echo $i;done`

Comment: Bash has many reliable ways to generate a range of integers. It's almost never necessary or particularly more usable to use `seq`. In this case `for ((val=from;val<=to;val++)); do echo $val; done`